# when to use module vs prototype?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Module pattern vs prototype pattern appear to do similar things in js. They essentially wrap a bunch of js code to encapsulate and provide a type of OO interface.  Are these techniques essentially interchangeable or are there scenarios where one of these techniques should be used instead of the other?

Comment: Modules and prototypes have very little overlap. Modules allow you to have multiple files with whatever you want in them, where as prototypes are a form of inheritance (not encapsulation).

Comment: you can check this out, see if it helps
[module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript), 
[revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript), 
[prototype pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#prototypepatternjavascript)